# Undefined Method 'findOneBy' when authenticating with symfony2 (as per docs)

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am trying to make a standard login authenticated from the database in symfony2.

I have followed the docs here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
and here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

My security File:

```
security:
encoders:
    Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: RWLoginBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My routing file:

```
login:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: RWLoginBundle:Default:login } 
login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check
```

but when I enter the user and password I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method RW\LoginBundle\Entity\User::findOneBy() in /var/www/rw/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php on line 55
```

my login page has been made according to the docs with the form and there is a redirect input there which goes to a url that does exist.

Has anybody come across anything like this before?

**Edit: added entity below**

```
namespace RW\LoginBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * RW\LoginBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RW\LoginBundle\Entity\User")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
```

Comment: hello, have you defined a custom repository for you user entity class ?  The EntityUserProvider  tries to find a user with your custom entity property 'username' using the default method  'findOneBy' defined in doctrine repository

Comment: There is a user class, which does have a username. (LoginBundle:User) Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, have defined a custom repository for this entity class ? ex with annotation /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */

Comment: yeah: `* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RW\LoginBundle\Entity\User")`

Comment: so make sure your repository class extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository, or implements interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository. If so, you must have a findOneBy(array $criteria)  method

Comment: Have added my entity into the post, i did work around the issue by removing the username property in the security file. this then defaulted to username, and it does not error... you still think there is an issue?

Comment: there is something weird, you defined your repositoryClass as your entity class, but this is wrong. You should have defined a repositoryClass like this "RW\LoginBundle\Repository\User" which extends "EntityRepository" or none if you don't need it

Comment: If you look in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#the-data-model) (2.1 version), this is the same?